# Follow docker port mapping inside container

Tags: web, docker, port

I have a cloud pc with static external ip, f.e. `162.243.100.100`
Inside I installed docker with nginx, and mapped 80 port like this

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 nginx
```

I'm able to access nginx demo page from `curl 162.243.100.100` from host machine.
I'm able to access nginx demo page from `curl localhost` from inside said container.

But I want to have able to access ngninx demo page from command `curl 162.243.100.100` from inside said nginx containeer.
Seem this not follow port mapping, and just give me timeout error.
I thin I need to do something with network settings, but not know what.

Comment: Why do you want to access it from that IP address inside the container? What's wrong with localhost?

Comment: `162.243.100.100` is the `host`'s IP Address, not the container's. The container is like another machine in the same or in a different network. Is that really what you need? It just doesn't make much sense out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "don't do that."

The default iptables rules and routing tables from Docker aren't setup to route traffic from a container out to the host and back into the container through the docker-proxy. Considering how much this is an anti-pattern, I don't expect it to be a priority to change this behavior. It's much easier to work with the tool and use docker networks and the container name when talking from container to container.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) and start your container in that network:

```
docker network create --subnet 172.16.0.0/16 dockernet

docker run -it -p 80:80 --net=dockernet nginx
```